# How can I get the 'root' boot arg in kernel space?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I am writing a driver and I need to know what disk/partition contains the root filesystem. This can be viewed from userspace using:

```
cat /proc/cmdline 
root=/dev/mmcblk0p1
```

How can I get the value of `root` in kernel space?

Comment: You most probably don't want the value of `root=` as that can have many different formats, for example `root=UUID=xxx`, `root=/dev/xxx`, `root=maj:min`, `root=PARTUUID=xxx/PARTNROFF=yyy`, and so on... if you need this inside a module, you most probably would like to know what `dev_t` device is the root device. Is this what you are after?

Comment: Ping! Care to address my comment? I have a simple solution for you if that's the case.

Comment: Oh yes, that would be great,thanks!

Comment: Done, there you go.

Comment: Thanks so much! You really went all out

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if that solved your problem. In such case you can accept the answer to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the `dev_t` for the device where your filesystem root is mounted, you can use a strategy similar to what the [`stat()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/stat.c#L246) syscall does. The only exception is that you are not working with `__user` buffers, so you'll need to use slightly different APIs.

In short, you want to:

1. Call [`kern_path()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/namei.c#L2419) to get a [`struct path`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/path.h#L8) for the path `"/"`.
2. Call [`vfs_getattr()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/stat.c#L110) passing that path to get a [`struct kstat`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/stat.h#L24).
3. Check the `->dev` member of the `struct kstat`, which is the root device (`dev_t`).
4. If you want, you can also use [`bdget()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/block_dev.c#L900) to find the block device corresponding to the obtained `dev_t`, then use [`bdevname()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/block/partition-generic.c#L47) to get its name (e.g. `sda1`).

This translates to the following:

```
struct path root_path;
struct kstat root_stat;
struct block_device *root_device;
char root_device_name[BDEVNAME_SIZE];

kern_path("/", 0, &root_path);

// KERNEL > 4.10
// vfs_getattr(&root_path, &root_stat, STATX_BASIC_STATS, AT_NO_AUTOMOUNT|AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW);

// KERNEL <= 4.10
vfs_getattr(&root_path, &root_stat);

pr_info("root device number is 0x%08x; major = %d, minor = %d\n", root_stat.dev, MAJOR(root_stat.dev), MINOR(root_stat.dev));

root_device = bdget(root_stat.dev);
bdevname(root_device, root_device_name);

pr_info("root device name: %s, path: /dev/%s\n", root_device_name, root_device_name);

bdput(root_device);
path_put(&root_path);
```

**Some notes:**

1. I did not do any kind of error checking in the above example, but you most definitely should! See the complete example below.
2. `kern_path()` seems to take `LOOKUP_*` flags defined in `linux/namei.h` as
   second argument, but passing a default value of `0` is also ok.
3. Likewise, `vfs_getattr()` takes `STATX_*` flags defined in `linux/stat.h` as
   third arg. The `stat()` syscall passes `STATX_BASIC_STATS`, but passing `0`
   should be fine too here since we do not need to know anything other
   than the device (`->dev` field), which *seems* to get populated
   regardless of flags. I could not test this though since my kernel is <= 4.10, and these flags are necessary only for kernel > 4.10.

### Working example

Here's a complete example of a working kernel module which does the above also applying proper error checking.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
#include <linux/kernel.h>     // printk(), pr_*()
#include <linux/module.h>     // THIS_MODULE, MODULE_VERSION, ...
#include <linux/init.h>       // module_{init,exit}
#include <linux/types.h>      // dev_t
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>     // MAJOR(), MINOR(), MKDEV()
#include <linux/path.h>       // struct path
#include <linux/namei.h>      // kern_path(), path_put()
#include <linux/stat.h>       // struct kstat, STATX_*
#include <linux/fs.h>         // vfs_getattr(), struct block_device, bdget(),...
#include <uapi/linux/fcntl.h> // AT_*

#ifdef pr_fmt
#undef pr_fmt
#endif
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt

static int __init findrootdev_init(void)
{
    struct path root_path;
    struct kstat root_stat;
    struct block_device *root_device;
    char root_device_name[BDEVNAME_SIZE];
    int err = 0;

    pr_info("init\n");

    err = kern_path("/", 0, &root_path);
    if (err) {
        pr_err("kern_path error %d\n", err);
        goto kern_path_fail;
    }

    // KERNEL > 4.10
    // err = vfs_getattr(&root_path, &root_stat, STATX_BASIC_STATS,
    //        AT_NO_AUTOMOUNT|AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW);

    // KERNEL <= 4.10
    err = vfs_getattr(&root_path, &root_stat);

    if (err) {
        pr_err("vfs_getattr error %d\n", err);
        goto vfs_getattr_fail;
    }

    pr_info("root device number is 0x%08x; major = %d, minor = %d\n",
        root_stat.dev, MAJOR(root_stat.dev), MINOR(root_stat.dev));

    root_device = bdget(root_stat.dev);
    if (!root_device) {
        pr_err("bdget failed\n");
        err = -1;
        goto bdget_fail;
    }

    if (!bdevname(root_device, root_device_name)) {
        pr_err("bdevname failed\n");
        err = -1;
        goto bdevname_fail;
    }

    pr_info("root device name: %s, path: /dev/%s\n",
        root_device_name, root_device_name);

bdevname_fail:
    bdput(root_device);

bdget_fail:
vfs_getattr_fail:
    path_put(&root_path);

kern_path_fail:
    return err;
}

static void __exit findrootdev_exit(void)
{
    // This function is only needed to be able to unload the module.
    pr_info("exit\n");
}

module_init(findrootdev_init);
module_exit(findrootdev_exit);
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Silly test module to find the root device and its name.");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Marco Bonelli");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Compiling and loading the above module with `insmod` generates this output in `dmesg`:

```
[12664.685699] findrootdev: init
[12664.685703] findrootdev: root device number is 0x00800003; major = 8, minor = 3
[12664.685706] findrootdev: root device name: sda3, path: /dev/sda3
[12671.671038] findrootdev: exit
```